# Can I build http server with Python?

Tags: python, http, server

I try build simple http server. I want to use: context manager, class and inheritance:

**main.py**

```
from server.class_http_handler import HTTPHandler
from http.server import HTTPServer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with HTTPServer(('', 8000), HTTPHandler("<h1>Paragraph</h1>")) as server:
       server.serve_forever()
```

**class_http_handler.py**

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class HTTPHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, content):
       self.content = content

    def __enter__(self):
        self.__start = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Title of the document</title></head><body>"
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.__stop = "</body></html>"
        self.__difference = self.__start + self.content + self.__stop

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()

        message = self.content
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
```

The server starts but return stacktrace with errors:

```
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: 'HTTPHandler' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can build a HTTP server in python. But **its not recommended to use in production**. As defined in python 3.9 docs (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html ), you can start a http server by using

```py
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    server_address = ('', 8000)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

> You can also add this to your class and call it in the **init** method to call it for every object.

this will start your http server on your localhost ip with port 8000. You can use likely 90% of the functions and libraries with this http server (including object oriented features).

***And also see your class_http_handler.py line:9. It has indentation issues.***

Comment: Thank you for short answer. How implements HTTP methods so that you can show simple web page ?